# deploy to Github Package Registry from Github Action

Tags: maven, github, github-actions, github-package-registry

I would like to deploy to a GitHub Package Registry from a GitHub Action of a public repo.

I have a yml file for a workflow:

```
name: My CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: lein deps
    - name: Run tests
      run: lein test
    - name: Generate pom
      run: lein pom
    - name: Deploy
      run: mvn deploy
```

I use Leiningen to build the project and generate a POM file. Then I would like to use Maven to deploy the artifact to the GitHub Package Registry.

This fails on the `Deploy` command (I have replaced personal information with `...`):

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata ... from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/.../...): Not authorized
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  19.343 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-29T13:08:42Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project ...: Failed to retrieve remote metadata .../maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata ... from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/.../...): Not authorized -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I see that authentication failed. I have also tried with this step with the same results:

```
run: mvn deploy -Dserver.username=... -Dserver.password=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} -DskipTests
```

I do not want to supply username/password or token as this is a public repository. Is there a way to publish anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work to specify `env: GITHUB_TOKEN=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` and then use `$GITHUB_TOKEN` in the command line? I'm not in the GitHub Actions beta yet so I can't test this for myself.

Answer (score 13):

TL;DR: Just commit the following to `.github/workflows/mavenpublish.yml` and create a release via the GitHub web page to trigger the process:

```yaml
name: Maven Package

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      - name: Deploy to Github Package Registry
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.m2
          echo "<settings><servers><server><id>gh</id><username>$(echo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" | awk -F / '{print $1}')</username><password>\${env.GITHUB_TOKEN}</password></server></servers></settings>" > ~/.m2/settings.xml
          REPO="gh::default::https://maven.pkg.github.com/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}"
          mvn deploy -DaltReleaseDeploymentRepository="${REPO}" -DaltSnapshotDeploymentRepository="${REPO}"
```

Some more info:

I have built the same thing before [for Jenkins](https://github.com/cloudogu/ces-build-lib/blob/develop/src/com/cloudogu/ces/cesbuildlib/Maven.groovy) and can tell you that you don't need to create a `settings.xml` nor adapt your `pom.xml` in your repo.

You can even avoid writing your GitHub Token into the `settings.xml` (which is more secure).

Also, you don't need to manually add your repo and username, these can be read from the environment.

If you want it to build on push, just change the lines behind `on:` to `[push]`.

Here`s a [real-life example](https://github.com/schnatterer/smeagol/blob/b8c71473bb210cd4a9f54befb4147dc05a55fba6/.github/workflows/mavenpublish.yml).

Comment: What does `gh::default::` do in the repo URL?

Comment: The format of the `altReleaseDeploymentRepository` system property is as follows: `id::layout::url`. That is, `gh` is the `id` of the repo (matching the `<id>` in the `settings.xml`) and `default` is the layout. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altDeploymentRepository

Answer (score 12):

To make it work, you need to do two things:

1. Add the following to your pom.xml:

```xml
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
     <id>github</id>
     <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
     <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

source: https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-package-registry#publishing-a-package

2. Setup a Maven settings file with the username/password from within your build action.
   In my case I did something like this:

```
name: Java CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Deploy to Github Package Registry
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: |
        mkdir ~/.m2
        echo "<settings><servers><server><id>github</id><username>OWNER</username><password>${GITHUB_TOKEN}</password></server></servers></settings>" > ~/.m2/settings.xml
        mvn deploy
```

Unfortunately, I don't think you can pass the username/password as arguments to Maven and so you need to set up the settings file instead.
source: [Is it possible to pass a password in Maven Deploy in the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071697/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-password-in-maven-deploy-in-the-command-line)

Lastly, I confirm that this only works for non-SNAPSHOT artifacts. When I try deploying a SNAPSHOT version it fails with a 400 error as described.

Answer (score 6):

There is an easier way in **2020**.

First, add distribution configuration to your pom.xml:

```
<distributionManagement>
 <repository>
  <id>github</id>
  <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
  <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY</url>
 </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

The `id` must be github.

Second, use `actions/setup-java@v1` in action

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
    with:
      java-version: 1.8

  - name: Publish to GitHub Packages
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
    run: mvn deploy
```

Comment: Absolutely right. You can also change the `repository` `id` to something different than `github` - you only need to add another configuration parameter beneath the `java-version` named `server-id: yourOtherIdHere` inside the  `actions/setup-java@v1` section.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue for my project.
Every time I ran `mvn deploy`, it failed with:

> Could not transfer metadata ... from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/.../...): 400

However, on a whim, I changed the version number of my project from *0.0.3-SNAPSHOT* to *0.0.4* and after that, it worked.

Maybe it will work for you too.

Comment: Does not work in my project at all. No matter if I deploy SNAPSHOT or non-SNAPSHOT versions: https://github.com/m-m-m/base
To me it seems as if github actions with github packages are kind of alpha status. I have sent a request to github support and did not get any feedback since 3 weeks.

Answer (score 4):

Well, According to:

- [maven command line how to point to a specific settings.xml for a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25279325/11533303)
- [GitHub package registry as Maven repo - trouble uploading artifact](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/GitHub-package-registry-as-Maven-repo-trouble-uploading-artifact/m-p/28832)

I think you could simply do like this:

1. Add below to your workflow

```
- name: Deploy to Github Package Registry
    env:
      GITHUB_USERNAME: x-access-token
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    run:
      mvn --settings settings.xml deploy
```

2. And then add settings.xml to your project

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>github</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>github</id>
                    <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
                    <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER </url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>github</id>
            <username>${env.GITHUB_USERNAME}</username>
            <password>${env.GITHUB_TOKEN}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

It works for me, I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

In *2024* this is the suggested way (by `github` itself):

1. Edit the `distributionManagement` element of the pom.xml file located in your package directory, replacing `OWNER` with the name of the personal account or organization that owns the repository and `REPOSITORY` with the name of the repository containing your project.

   ```
   <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>github</id>
        <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
        <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY</url>
      </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
   ```
2. Create a `.github/workflows/deploy.yml` file.

   ```
   # This workflow will build a package using Maven and then publish it to GitHub packages when a release is created
   # For more information see: https://github.com/actions/setup-java/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#apache-maven-with-a-settings-path

   name: Maven Package

   on:
     release:
       types: [created]

   jobs:
     build:

       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       permissions:
         contents: read
         packages: write

       steps:
       - uses: actions/checkout@v3
       - name: Set up JDK 11
         uses: actions/setup-java@v3
         with:
           java-version: '11'
           distribution: 'temurin'
           server-id: github # Value of the distributionManagement/repository/id field of the pom.xml
           settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }} # location for the settings.xml file

       - name: Build with Maven
         run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml

       - name: Publish to GitHub Packages Apache Maven
         run: mvn deploy -s $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/settings.xml
         env:
           GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
   ```
3. To load the package from a private repository add this file to the `~/.m2/settings.xml` file:

   ```
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

      <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
      </activeProfiles>

      <profiles>
        <profile>
          <id>github</id>
          <repositories>
            <repository>
              <id>central</id>
              <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
              <id>github</id>
              <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY</url>
              <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
              </snapshots>
            </repository>
          </repositories>
        </profile>
      </profiles>

      <servers>
        <server>
          <id>github</id>
          <username>USERNAME</username>
          <password>TOKEN</password>
        </server>
      </servers>
    </settings>
   ```
4. To create the TOKEN you could follow something like these steps:

- Click on Personal Access Tokens, Generate new token (classic)
  [image: GenerateNewTokenClassic]
- Select `read:packages`
  [image: SelectReadPackages]