# Error Code 400 when trying to (maven) deploy to github packages using github actions

Tags: java, maven, github, repository, pipeline

I am struggling with the (seemingly) simple task of deploying a maven project to github packages using a github actions workflow. First of all, here's the error I am getting in the `maven deploy` phase:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project [project name]: Failed to retrieve remote metadata [groupId]:[artifactId]:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata [groupId]:[artifactId]:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/[username]/[repository]): Failed to transfer file https://maven.pkg.github.com/[username]/[repository]/[groupId as path]/[artifactId]/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml with status code 400 -> [Help 1]
```

(Info: I replaced unneccessary and/or private concrete information with general terms in [brackets])

Most likely, the actual maven-metadata.xml file is not the problem because I have already seen warnings like "could not upload checksum" with status 400 before. I guess that maven-metadata.xml is just the first file it fails on, but probably I am completely wrong with this assumption, please tell me if so.

Probably the most important file is the workflow yaml file:

```
name: Deploy SNAPSHOT (develop)

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11
      - name: Maven Deploy
        env:
          GITHUB_USERNAME: x-access-token
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: mvn --settings settings.xml -B -e -Dmaven.wagon.http.pool=false clean deploy
```

Also quite important: the maven settings.xml file:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>github-packages</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>github-packages</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>github</id>
                    <name>GitHub [username] Apache Maven Packages</name>
                    <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/[username]</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>github</id>
            <username>${env.GITHUB_USERNAME}</username>
            <password>${env.GITHUB_TOKEN}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

(Info: same goes for values in brackets as before)

And lastly, the parent pom.xml of my maven project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>[groupId]</groupId>
    <artifactId>[artifactId]</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        [child modules]
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        [my dependencies]
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>GitHub [username] Apache Maven Packages</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/[username]/[repository]</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>


</project>
```

Maybe it's also important to say that the GitHub repository belongs entirely to me and therefore I should have all admin rights on it.

## Things I've tried:

I have done some research by now and I found that my issue seems to be not uncommon. Although, from all solutions I've found so far, not one has worked.

1. [Official GitHub documentation for setting up workflows](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/configuring-a-workflow)

To start of, I used this site as my reference.

2. [This StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711558/deploy-to-github-package-registry-from-github-action)

I mostly stuck to all the advice I found in this question and in the answers to it.

3. [This other StackOverflow Question about nexus deploys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649486/error-when-deploying-an-artifact-in-nexus)

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18702353) of this question provides a checklist. I tried to check that all the bullet points work for me, although I wasn't able to validate everything. I did not find any issue based on this checklist.

4. [This question on the GitHub community forum](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/GitHub-Package-Registry-with-Maven-causes-deployment-issues/m-p/39929#M4022)

The error displayed in this question looks **very much** like the error I am getting, still the proposed solution did not fix anything for me.

5. [This Answer on a similar GitHub community forum question](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/GitHub-package-registry-as-Maven-repo-trouble-uploading-artifact/m-p/31689/highlight/true#M2990)

This answer suggested using a personal access token instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN`. I tried that and it changed nothing.

## What I need

Of course I'd be happy if someone can show me what the exact issue of my case is, but it does not need to be that specific. I am trying to set up the most basic pipeline possible and I currently don't want to do more than just deploy a maven snapshot repository to github packages (with github actions). So, if anyone can show me how to do this properly *in general*, that's also fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kinda figured it out myself, but the result is very dissatisfying. The main problem here is:

> Note: GitHub Packages does not support SNAPSHOT versions of Apache Maven. Make sure you disable SNAPHOT in your ~/.m2/settings.xml file.

([Source](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages))

So, it seems like GitHub Packages does not support the construct of maven snapshot repositories, which are otherwise very practical. My plan was to set up a workflow that deploys a new SNAPSHOT on the package registry when a push to develop happens. Maven snapshot repositories do not require unique version numbers for deploys, which means I could have built a new version for every push, but the actual dependency version stays fixed. Everyone could then easily try out the latest state of my `develop` branch, simply by including the fixed snapshot version in their pom files.

Now, how to fix my issue:

Because GitHub packages does not support snapshot repositories, you will have to remove the keyword "`SNAPSHOT`" from the value in the `project.version` tag in your pom file. Basically you can put every other version description there, but now it is unique. However if you remove all `SNAPSHOT` keywords, the workflow should properly deploy a package to the GitHub package registry, at least it worked for me.

If anyone knows a way to "hack" around this `SNAPSHOT` issue, please tell me. Otherwise this is the only working solution I've found so far.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and after copying your solution exactly I still get "Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact" when the deploy phase tries to upload the pom. Can you post the complete, final working files? POM, .yml, and settings.xml?

Comment: @ccleve I solved this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398972/38368 (with snapshots working partially - works for Maven, fails for spark submit).

Comment: As of 2022, GitHub supports `-SNAPSHOT` versions just fine; we actually use it exclusively as a snapshot repository, while release versions (non-snapshot) go to Maven Central.