# Pass artifactory access token to maven through commandline?

Tags: maven, artifactory

Is there a way to pass an artifactory token to maven via command line instead of adding it to the settings.xml file while performing a clean and build?

I tried with `-Dartifactory.accessToken` but it was not working.

Comment: If this is some kind of script or CI, I would use an environment variable for the access token.

Answer (score 0):

An access token can be used as password.
As mentioned in the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071697/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-password-in-maven-deploy-in-the-command-line), you can use variables in your `setting.xml` and provide values via the command line.

For example, in your `settings.xml` use -

```xml
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <username>${artifactory.username}</username>
            <password>${artifactory.accessToken}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

(it assumes there is a `<repository>` defined with `<id>artifactory</id>`, but it can be changed)

Then in the command line, use -

```bash
$ mvn -Dartifactory.username=<username> \
      -Dartifactory.accessToken=<accesstoken> \
      clean install
```